# The scope of $scope

Tags: angularjs, scope

I have done a very small code on Plunkr under URL http://plnkr.co/wbVjBfpAA9WTpjEAs1GJ

I define first a Array Object which I display on a page with ng-repeat. No problem

Then on each item I add an Edit button and launch a function on ng-click

Now, I copy the selected array item into a new $scope.contractDetail and display this in the edit section (as input).

To my surprise when I start to edit the text in the input field, not only the $scope.contractDetail object gets updated but also the parent $scope.contracts.

I though I would, after edit to assign my $scontractDetail object specifically back into the $scope.contracts object at the given index.

Can somebody explain to me whta is happening here

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Copying your code from the plunkr to show:

```
angular.module('plunker', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.contracts = [{title: 'Master License Agreement'},{title: 'Limited Use Agreement'},{title: 'NDA'}];

  $scope.editContract = function(indx){
    $scope.contractDetail = $scope.contracts[indx];
  }
})
```

Objects in JavaScript are essentially passed by reference, so when you set:

```
$scope.contractDetail = $scope.contracts[indx];
```

The two objects are the same object. When you begin to edit it, Android's dirty checking picks that up and shows the change in the other spot.

If you want to create a copy to edit (for an edit + save/cancel scenario) you can use `angular.copy(obj)` to create a duplicate that is not the same object.

Comment: many thanks for these hints. i will try to use the angular.copy(obj)